# Tokens for taxonomy term parents in Drupal 8 Pathauto

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to find the correct tokens to use for a Pathauto pattern in Drupal 8.

In Drupal 7, I have a Pathauto module pattern that creates a URL alias with a node's term and parent term.

So if the node had a Term reference of *Health -> Diet*. The URL would be `health/diet/node-title`.

The pattern to generate this is `[node:field-topic:0:parents:join-path]/[node:field-topic:0]/[node:title]`

Note the `:0` is because the Term reference field allows multiple values.

Comment: Appears this may not exist in Drupal 8 yet https://www.drupal.org/node/2821810

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Berdir here for the help https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224607/tokens-for-taxonomy-term-parents-in-pathauto/224754#224754

The tokens have changed a bit since Drupal 7. See example below.

Token: `/articles/[node:field_tags:0:entity:parents:join-path]/[node:field_tags:0:entity]/[node:title]`

Tag hierachy: A > B > C

Alias for an article tagged with C: `/articles/a/b/c/pathauto-test`